# Do these numbers form a group? $e^{2πi(m/n)},m=1,2,....n-1,n \in N^{*}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Do these numbers form a group under standard multiplication? $$e^{2πi(m/n)}$$ where $n \in N^{*}$ and $m=1,2,....n-1$

I think that there isn't an identity element cause $m$ is never $0$.
Is that correct??

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: Another way to see it is: The set is not closed under multiplication. For example, if $a=e^{2πi(1/n)}$ and $b=e^{2πi((n-1)/n)}$, then $ab$ is not in the set.

Comment: @quasi $m=n$ gives the  identity

Comment: @quasi It's a little unclear because there are two commas, but $m$ is allowed to be $n$ apparently, in which case it is a group.

Comment: I interpreted it as $m$ going from $1$ to $n-1$. Look at the title of the posted question.

Comment: @quasi  I think you're right.  the last $n$ is written to tell us that $n$ is a natural number.  It's not part of delimiters for $m$.  IMO.

Comment: @figarozo: Bottom line: If $m$ goes from $1$ to $n$, then it's a group. If $m$ goes from $1$ to $n-1$, then it's not a group. But now you can see how a minor notational confusion can wreck things!

Comment: thank you all guys yes m cannot be n only n-1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct. It is not a group because there is no identity.

Comment: but m is only 1,2,3,...n-1????not n

Comment: @figarozo You wrote $1,2,\ldots.n-1,,n$, to be precise. So the $n$ is there. You're saying it's a typo?

Comment: yes yes sorry my fault then i ll fix it

Comment: i hope that's more clear

Comment: @figarozo Yes. I've edited my answer accordingly.